# PHP memory exhausted ( json_decode)

Tags: php, json, memory

When my application tries to decodes large (15K~ rows) JSON string (comes from CURL), it fails with:

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 91 bytes)

I know I can expand the memory limit or unlimit it, however I'd rather avoid that. I have been wondering whether there is a different approach to address that kind of issue - such splitting the JSON string into small chunks (like `array_chunk`).

**UPDATE**

Just to make sure that the issue is not caused by any other function / loop in the app, I've extract the JSON string into a file and tried to decode it directly from the file (file size = 11.8MB). still fails.

```
$y = json_decode( file_get_contents('/var/tmp/test.txt') );
```

**UPDATE 2**
The script runs on Mac OS X environment. I've tested it also on Ubunto env (also 128M memory limit) - and there it works perfectly. should i be concern?

Comment: Just how big is this JSON string? Because 128Mb is a LOT of memory...

Comment: The number of rows doesn't tell the size

Comment: those 15k rows how much data is in each row (about how much)? 

would help there to decide how to best help you there. 

Also is there anything else taking place like the part where the allowed memory is passed being part of a loop,....? (it could be that even though the json is where the error happens that it is not the reason if a memory leak is happening at an ealier instance in a loop for example)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol "MB" not "Mb". Significant difference.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Whoops, indeed. Then again, 128Mb (16MB) is still a LOT of RAM to be using in a single PHP script.

Comment: @Niet - the UK Labour party political manifesto for the last general election made the same mistake, guaranteeing 100MB broadband to every home in Britain).... I'd really have loved it if they'd won the election, and then realised what they'd actually promised

Comment: I managed to do that a few times myself (with 500 MB even) but it was always a memory leak in a large loop  so the mainquesiton is is the single row in his json so large or is there a memory leak problem in a loop and the json command is just the poor victim in the equation

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yes, I upvoted your comment regardless units mistake :)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Maybe you should read about units in computing? :-) 1 byte = 8 bit. 134217728 bytes = 134 MB (million bytes) = 1072 Mb (million bits).

Comment: @thedom How have you calculated it? 1 kB = 1024 B, 1 MB = 1024 kB, so it seems it 128 MB and not 134 MB

Comment: the file size is 11.8MB

Comment: @thedom And how do you know I didn't just let go of the Shift key just a little too soon? :p

Comment: @Dan can you post the exact commands you used for the blank php file? that should help greatly there to decipher your problem as it still failed there (11.8mb json file shouldnt cause that problem when decoding)

Comment: @ThomasE. $y = json_decode( file_get_contents('/var/tmp/test.txt') );

Comment: @Dan Pls put that also into the question above pls. and that is the full content of the php file? (did you also test if file_get_contents functions if used alone)?

Comment: @ThomasE. yes for both. i'm 100% sure the json_decode causes the issue.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Actually I don't know ;-p...

Answer (score 4):

To permanently avoid this, use an event-based JSON parser like https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser.

That way, the whole thing doesn't have to be in memory at once.  Instead, you process the events which give you one piece of the object/array at a time.

Answer (score 2):

There are no other PHP functions that let you decode JSON string. You can try on your own or find library to split JSON into parts.

However you should make sure that it's the only problem. For example before decoding JSON data you maybe created big arrays or create many objects.

If I were you, I would save this json string to file and write extra script just to get it from file and decode to make sure that using json_decode makes the only problem.

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest ways to iterate big json file in php is to use [halaxa/json-machine](https://github.com/halaxa/json-machine). You only write one `foreach`. It will never hit memory limit, because it parses one item a at a time behind the scenes, so the memory consumption is constant no matter the file size.